# WooCommerce get post tags for products in product category - archive-product.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to customize functionality and do own filter in product categories by manufacturers (manufacturers are in product_tag taxonomy) but I can't figure it out..The theme using archive-product.php for category page..

I have the category id this way:

```
$obj = get_queried_object(); 
$cat_id = $obj->term_id;
```

I trying to get tags for each category by this code but form is empty. :(

```
    function get_tags_in_use($category_ID, $type = 'name'){
    // Set up the query for our posts
    $my_posts = new WP_Query(array(
      'cat' => $category_ID, // Your category id
      'posts_per_page' => -1 // All posts from that category
    ));

    // Initialize our tag arrays
    $tags_by_id = array();
    $tags_by_name = array();
    $tags_by_slug = array();

    // If there are posts in this category, loop through them
    if ($my_posts->have_posts()): while ($my_posts->have_posts()): $my_posts->the_post();

      // Get all tags of current post
      $post_tags = wp_get_post_tags($my_posts->post->ID);

      // Loop through each tag
      foreach ($post_tags as $tag):

        // Set up our tags by id, name, and/or slug
        $tag_id = $tag->term_id;
        $tag_name = $tag->name;
        $tag_slug = $tag->slug;

        // Push each tag into our main array if not already in it
        if (!in_array($tag_id, $tags_by_id))
          array_push($tags_by_id, $tag_id);

        if (!in_array($tag_name, $tags_by_name))
          array_push($tags_by_name, $tag_name);

        if (!in_array($tag_slug, $tags_by_slug))
          array_push($tags_by_slug, $tag_slug);

      endforeach;
    endwhile; endif;

    // Return value specified
    if ($type == 'id')
        return $tags_by_id;

    if ($type == 'name')
        return $tags_by_name;

    if ($type == 'slug')
        return $tags_by_slug;
}

function get_some_tags_man($category_ID){
    $tags = get_tags_in_use($category_ID, 'name');

    // Start our output variable
    $html .= '<form name="terms" id="someID">';
    // Cycle through each tag and set it up
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        // Get our count
        $term = get_term_by('id', $tag, 'post_tag');
        $count = $term->count;

        // Get tag name
        $tag_info = get_tag($tag);
        $tag_name = $tag_info->name;


        $html .= "<input type='checkbox' id='$term->slug' name='$term->slug' value='$term->name'><label for='$term->slug'>$term->name</label><br>";
    }
    
    $html .= '</form>';
    return $html;
}
```

And here I trying to ouput:

```
echo get_some_tags_man($cat_id);
```

On this URL address: https://proairsoft.cz/airsoftove-zbrane/